# Size of the AVRO message in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

How can I calculate the size of the AVRO message in Kafka?

Answer (score 1):

Serialization format is irrelevant. You'll can get the length of the serialized byte array returned from the Serializer's `serialize` method